# amazon ec2 - how do you add storage?

Tags: amazon-ec2

1 How do you add storage to your Amazon Ec2 servers?
Say you need extra HDD space? or another drive?

2 how much does extra storage cost?

3 can I scale from Small Instance to large instance and not lose any data?

Comment: What did Amazon support say when you asked them? You did ask them, didn't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can create new [EBS volumes](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) and attach them to a running instance.
2. See the "Projecting Costs" section at the end of the link above.
3. Sure, if your data is on an EBS volume; you can detach the EBS volume from your small instance and reattach it to a large instance.  If it's not on an EBS volume, you can create a custom AMI from your running small instance, then start a large instance using the custom AMI.